# How to split word not a single character in Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I would like to split this string by a word "data::" not by single character. How?

```
String bla = "data::01000100010001000100data::0101001010101010101data::11111111111111111";
String result[] = bla.split("\\data::");
/*
 * this outputs the whole string
 * instead of only: 01000100010001000100*/
System.out.println(result[0]);
```

**Note:**

```
    package test;        
    public class NewClass 
    {    
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {     
          String bla = "data::0000data::1111data::010101";

          // Try 1 - failed
          String[] parta = bla.split("\\ddata::");
          System.out.println(parta[0]);        
          System.out.println(parta[1]);        
          System.out.println(parta[2]);        

          // Try 2 - failed -- works
          String[] partb = bla.split("data::");
          System.out.println(partb[0]); // consider as empty
          System.out.println(partb[1]); // starts from here
          System.out.println(partb[2]); 

          // Try 3 - failed
          String partc[] = bla.split("\\wdata::");
          System.out.println(partc[0]);        
          System.out.println(partc[1]);        
          System.out.println(partc[2]);                            
        }
    }
```

Failed Output:

```
run:
data::000
111
010101

0000
1111

data::000
111
010101

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `"\\data::"` with `"data::"`?

Comment: In try 2 of your example you need to print out `partb[3]`. Because your input starts with a separator, you're going to get an empty string as the first result. Using Guava'a `Splitter` as suggested by @John B, you could use `omitEmptyStrings()` to automatically ignore that extra result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\\d` inside a string literal denotes a digit in regex. You need to split on simply this:

```
bla.split("data::")
```

Because there is no single digit followed by `ata::` (the pattern: `"\\data::"`), the entire string is returned by `String.split(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String bla = "data::01000100010001000100data::0101001010101010101data::11111111111111111";
String result[] = bla.split("data::");
```

Test -

```
System.out.println(result[0]) //empty
System.out.println(result[1]) //01000100010001000100
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Guava's Splitter class [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

```
Iterable<String> result = Splitter.on("data::").split(bla);
```

Ok, looking at the other responses might be overkill but worth checking out. It is a really nice tool since it allows things such as "omitEmptyStrings" and "trimResults".

Comment: I'm hesitant to use an external library for something that is so eaily done in Java's core `String` class.

Comment: @Bart: `Splitter` has the advantage of `omitEmptyStrings()` here, since it seems the OP doesn't want the extra empty string at the start. And, as always with this sort of thing, it's not worth it to add a library just for this one thing... the library provides many other useful features that make it worth it.